# Is there a Windows 11 equivalent to Mac's "App shortcuts" in the keyboard preferences?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

My specific case: I use DaVinci Resolve to edit videos, and I have a few UI layouts saved. These can be accessed in the Workspace menu up top, but the button for loading them is a few layers deep, and they can't be assigned a keyboard shortcut from within the program like most other actions can.

On Mac, I'm able to go to System Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts, add DaVinci Resolve as a target app, then manually type the menu path for my custom action to load the UI preset. I can't find such a feature on Windows 11; can it be done?

Alternatively, I could program a macro to open the menu using Alt and go through it with a series of hotkeys, but that seems unreliable and not nearly as clean if there is a direct option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows doesn't have such functionality by default.

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) as a very commonly utilized alternative. It has a well-written documentation, e.g.:

- [binding keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/FileSelectFile.htm)
- window interactions, such as [Control](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Control.htm), etc.
- window detection, such as [WinExists](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinExist.htm), etc.

also tools that can help you identify the right handles/positions, like:

```
C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\WindowSpy.ahk
```

and a lot of other resources around the web, especially on their forums.

It's a very powerful tool, but you need to learn it.

Comment: Ah! Completely forgot about the existence of AHK. Pretty sure that'll work, thanks!